# Creating a div box through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying this code but it's not working.please help. in this I just want to create a div block and change its properties?

```
<html>
<head>
<script >
function create()
{
l=document.createElement('div');
l.id='10';
l.style.position='absolute';
l.style.top='100px';
l.style.left='200px';
l.style.height='100px';
l.style.width='100px';
l.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
l.style.zIndex='100';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" name="cssandcreate" id="cssandcreate" value="css"  onclick="create()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't count as an error description. What is happening instead?

Comment: @JanDvorak Nothing is happening instead, OP is clearly attempting to add an object to the DOM.

Comment: @Jonathan I got that, but the asker should tell us. We shouldn't be asked to guess. Maybe we've missed a typo in addition to the logical error?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just create element and wait till it will appear, you should also add it to the DOM .

Example :

```
document.body.appendChild(l);
```

Comment: Should be `document.body.appendChild(l);`

Comment: @user2828274 : Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 function createDiv() {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
        divTag.id = "div1";
        divTag.className = "divdrag";

        par = document.getElementById('stage'); 

        par.insertBefore(divTag, par.firstChild);
    }

    createDiv();
```

**CSS**

```
.divdrag{
          width:688px;
          position:relative;
          margin-top:20px;
          display:inline-block;
          height:50px;
            border: 1px solid red;

         }
        .divdrag:hover{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #999;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #999;
        border:0.7px dotted;
            }
```

Take a look at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3ZPEy/1/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="cssandcreate" id="cssandcreate" value="css"  onclick="create()"/>
```

JS

```
function create() {
    var l = document.createElement('div');
    l.id = '10';
    l.style.position = 'absolute';
    l.style.top = '100px';
    l.style.left = '200px';
    l.style.height = '100px';
    l.style.width = '100px';
    l.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    l.style.zIndex = '100';
    document.body.appendChild(l);
}
```